# trouble creating a box-shadow type effect with divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a solid box-shadow type effect without using CSS3. I'm constrained by a rich text editor's inflexible nature, and the need to have all styling in-line

Essentially, I need to place one div over another, slightly offset down, and right, div and have both centered and expand vertically with the amount of text I place withinin the top div.

I've included my best try at making it work here: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jameshenson/XfPNB/)

CSS :

```
#firstDiv {
   clear:left; 
   margin-top:30px; 
   padding: 0 30 0 30;
}

#secondDiv {
   display: table; 
   clear:left; position: relative; 
   margin:auto; 
   width:70%; 
   padding:60 50 60 20; 
   background: #ccc;   
}

#thirdDiv {
   width:100%; 
   position: absolute; 
   top: -20px; 
   bottom: 20px; 
   right: 20px;  
   padding: 20px; 
   background: #fff; 
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
   clear: left;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="#firstDiv">
  <div id="#secondDiv">
    <div id="#thirdDiv">
      <!--My long Text-->
      <p style="text-align: center">Lorem ipsum ...</p>
      <p style="text-align: center">Lorem ipsum ...</p>
      <p style="text-align: center">Lorem ipsum ...</p>
      <p style="text-align: center">Lorem ipsum ...</p>
      <p style="text-align: center">Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking...can you draw a crude picture or something?

Comment: @djbhindi He wants the box shadow effect that he has in his JSFiddle to extend such that it contains the paragraphs which currently appear to be overflowing the div.

Comment: @TylerH Oh. He could have just said that ^^, would have been much clearer. Anyway, looks like bardzusny has made that fix, if that is what he wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve your desired effect with two relative DIVs:

```
<div style="width: 70%; margin: 30px auto; position: relative; background-color: #ccc;">

<div style="position: relative; top: -20px; right: 20px; bottom: 20px; left: -20px; padding: 20px; background: #fff; border: 2px solid #ccc;">
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/Jjun9/)

Comment: Cleaned up version: http://jsfiddle.net/Jjun9/6/. That's all that's needed with this approach.

Comment: Thanks @bardzusny, I missed removing some of the unnecessary styles and things applied by the OP

Comment: Also, this is another approach that kind of, sort of works. But here we are positioning div with /content/ (text), instead of the one merely representing shadow. Remove margins, paddings, and look what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/Jjun9/7/

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing something...this should suit you very fine. Just insert this css inline in your html. http://jsfiddle.net/XfPNB/3/

We cannot use pseudo-elements (inline css restricts us). So, just add some div to the one containing all your text/content. Set position: relative; on your top div, then on the one that will be its shadow:

```
background: grey;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
```

Basically make sure it's exactly the same size as your main div, and then put it /under/ it (z-index). Grey (or yellow?) background. That's your shadow.